# AngularJS directive not loading

Tags: html, angularjs

I have written a directive in AngularJS and trying to use the directive in a html page.

**directive.js**

```javascript
.directive('formFieldNew', function($timeout, FieldTypes) {
return {
    restrict : 'EA',
    templateUrl : '/common-licensing/resources/partials/subscriber/template.html',
    replace : true,
    scope : {
        record : '=',
        field : '@',
        live : '@',
        required : '@'
    },
    link : function($scope, element, attr) {
        $scope.$on('record:invalid', function() {
            $scope[$scope.field].$setDirty();
        });

        $scope.types = FieldTypes;

        $scope.remove = function(field) {
            delete $scope.record[field];
            $scope.blurUpdate();
        };

        $scope.blurUpdate = function() {
            if ($scope.live !== 'false') {
                $scope.record.$update(function(updatedRecord) {
                    $scope.record = updatedRecord;
                });
            }
        };
        var saveTimeout;
        $scope.update = function() {
            $timeout.cancel(saveTimeout);
            saveTimeout = $timeout($scope.blurUpdate, 1000);
        };
    }
};
```

**new.html**

```html
<form name='newContact' novalidate class='form-horizontal'>
<form-field-new ng-repeat='(k,v) in productTempDetailsLists' record='productTempDetailsLists' field='{{k}}'></form-field-new>
<button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='save()' ng-disabled='newContact.$invalid'> Create Contact </button> 

</form>
```

**template.html**

```html
<div>
<input ng-model='record[field][0]' type='{{record[field][1]}}' class='form control'/>
</div>
```

When I run the file I am getting the below error in my console.

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/tplrt?p0=formFieldNew&p1=%2Fcommon-licensing%2Fresources%2Fpartials%2Fsubscriber%2Ftemplate.html
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:65:275
    at http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:112:113
    at n.$eval (http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:126:15)
    at n.$digest (http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:123:106)
    at n.$apply (http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:126:293)
    at l (http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:81:240)
    at M (http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:85:342)
    at XMLHttpRequest.F.onload (http://localhost:8080/common-licensing/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js:86:367)
```

I tried adding the `<div>` tag for my new.html file as per the error log but it did not work. Please help me out.

Comment: It would appear that that `templateUrl` isn't a valid path.  Is that HTML really in a file called `template.js` or is that a typo? Everywhere else, the file is referred to as `template.html`

Comment: I was getting a 404 (Not Found) error for the other templateUrl path I tried. This path didn't show any such error so I assumed it was the correct path.

Comment: Anticipating a future problem, you are creating an isolate scope that will not be able to talk to the Form controller.  Certain built in features will not work this way.  You might `require: FormController' but  that may prove to get tricky.  I would just use `scope:true`

Comment: @Chandan, simply write a `template` instead of using `templateUrl` so we can check whether the issue is in the html template or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, wherein `templateURL` doesn't work with absolute URL's. To see this check this out wherein you will find same error http://plnkr.co/edit/NoSZjfIiCiRrCaBbsHiE?p=preview

Use relative URL's and Try below

```
.directive('formFieldNew', function($timeout, FieldTypes) {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    //Not sure if this is correct relative path. check 
    templateUrl : '../common-licensing/resources/partials/subscriber/template.html',
    replace : true,
    scope : {
        record : '=',
        field : '@',
        live : '@',
        required : '@'
    },
    link : function($scope, element, attr) {
        $scope.$on('record:invalid', function() {
            $scope[$scope.field].$setDirty();
        });

        $scope.types = FieldTypes;

        $scope.remove = function(field) {
            delete $scope.record[field];
            $scope.blurUpdate();
        };

        $scope.blurUpdate = function() {
            if ($scope.live !== 'false') {
                $scope.record.$update(function(updatedRecord) {
                    $scope.record = updatedRecord;
                });
            }
        };
        var saveTimeout;
        $scope.update = function() {
            $timeout.cancel(saveTimeout);
            saveTimeout = $timeout($scope.blurUpdate, 1000);
        };
    }
};
```